# How to point a Rails app to a different directory?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

So I have a WordPress site running inside a Rails site. So currently, the wordpress portion of the site lives in dev.domain.com whereas the main site lives on domain.com. I am trying to have the main domain.com point to the contents of the /dev/ folder using .htaccess

So here's my htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /dev/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

This code above is re-directing all the pages to the /dev/ site except for the home page. So domain.com/some-page will work but the index page doesn't work.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: out of curiosity - what happens if outside of your IfModule block you do something like: `DirectoryIndex blahblah.php` - does the redirect for index work then?

Comment: what happen when removing the line RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

Comment: @cyril: Same thing happens. The main site runs on ruby. So pretty sure it shouldnt even be index.php